# Is there an API method to update a data set on Citrix Netscaler

Tags: rest, netscaler

I have a data set of IPs on the netscaler which controls access to a vip. I need to update that using a script.
I have looked at nextgen api and nitro api but cannot see a good match for what I need to achieve.
Has anyone ever done this and if so how are you doing.
A consultant I worked with suggested creating a text file then uploading it over SSH and running shell commands to update the data set. Is there a better API method.

I thought i would be able to do this with the nextgen api and filter value sets
https://developer-docs.netscaler.com/en-us/nextgen-api/apis/#/Filters-Value-Sets/GetFilterValueSets
but whenever I try and access them I get an access denied error using an account which has the sysadmin rights